# Missing required modules: 'FirebaseAuthInterop', 'FirebaseCoreExtension', 'GTMSessionFetcherCore

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-storage

i am coding a project in Xcode, i have imported my firebase pods already. For some reason, i keep getting this error message and i cant figure out why. Can anyone help? The error message is " Missing required modules: 'FirebaseAuthInterop', 'FirebaseCoreExtension', 'GTMSessionFetcherCore "

My code:

```
import FirebaseStorage    // <---- this is where i am getting my error message

import Foundation

public class StorageManager{
    
    static let shared = StorageManager()
    
    // MARK: - Public
    
}
```

here is whats in my pod file:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Chall Champ' do
    use_frameworks!

pod ‘Appirater’

pod ‘Firebase/Core’

pod ‘Firebase/Auth’

pod ‘Firebase/Database’

pod ‘Firebase/Analytics’

pod ‘Firebase/Crashlytics’

pod ‘Firebase/Storage’


end
```

i tried updating my podfile and also restated Xcode to see if it was on there end

Answer (score 0):

Update to the Podfile `platform :ios, '11.0'`

Recent versions of Firebase require at least iOS 11

Comment: i have changed it to ios, 13.0 in xcode already

Answer (score 0):

Update your podfile and try

```
pod 'FirebaseAuth'
pod 'FirebaseStorage'
pod 'FirebaseCore'
pod 'FirebaseCoreExtension'
pod 'FirebaseAuthInterop'
```